# Integrate forms into C# WinForms project via NuGet package

Tags: c#, winforms, nuget, project, nuget-package

I am building a NuGet package for a WinForms control demonstrating how to use it. As such, I need to add some sample forms into the target project when my NuGet package is being installed. If the name of my sample form is Form2 and I integrate it into a default C# WinForms project, I get the following result in the solution explorer:

[image: Problem integrating form into C# WinForms project via NuGet]

As you can see, the Form2 is not added to the target project correctly. And really, if we look into the .csproj file, we'll find the following records for the code parts of the Form2:

```xml
<Compile Include="Form2.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form2.Designer.cs" />
```

, while the correct record for the Form2.Designer.cs file should be

```xml
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

(the same problem for Form2.resx).

What is interesting, VB forms are integrated into VB projects from a NuGet package without any problems, and this issue looks like a C#-specific NuGet issue.

Is there any way to solve this problem for C#?

Comment: If you want to demonstrate how to use it, wouldn't it be better to just create a public GitHub repo with your samples? Why does this need to be a NuGet package? NuGet should be for delivering class libraries - and that's it. Just DLL's.

Comment: @mason, why don't use NuGet for that if we can do all what we need in one pack? If the problem can be solved easily with a PowerShell script or a transformation file or something like that, then why not?

Comment: Because that's an abuse of NuGet. They've [deprecated install.ps1 support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/NuGet-3-What-and-Why/). There are better tools to share samples.